# Closing Zabbix problems through Grafana interface?

Tags: grafana, zabbix

There is
zabbix_server (Zabbix) 4.4.4
and Grafana v6.5.3

A template with problems from Zabbix is ​​configured, it is possible to confirm problems, but is it possible to close them from the interface of Grafana itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using the Zabbix Grafana Plugin from Alexander Zobnin.

Regarding your request: It's not possible right now, but there's a [feature request](https://github.com/alexanderzobnin/grafana-zabbix/issues/524) about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer provided.